# Como puedo hacer una lista donde solo puedo ingresar 3 notas y si son menos me salga una alerta

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que realizar un programa que pida por teclado la cantidad de notas a ingresar de un estudiante y en esta
validar que sea mayor a tres ingresos; y  si  no es así el programa no debe terminar sino
seguir pidiendo la cantidad de notas a ingresar, pero antes mostrar un mensaje por pantalla
alertando al usuario. Luego del ingreso correspondiente de la cantidad de notas, solicitar
dichas notas para que permita calcular el promedio y muestre el mismo pero estuve haciendo algunos códigos pero no me funcionan me salen error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar lo que pides, te dejo dos opciones:

La primera opción evita directamente que falte alguna nota y la iteración cumple con agregar todas las notas a la lista:

```
lista = []
for i in range(1, 3+1):
    nota = int(input(f'Ingresa la nota {i}: '))
    lista.append(nota)
print(lista)
```

La segunda cumple con la condicional para añadir una nota, en caso de que falte alguna, te arroja el mensaje, pero solo se me ocurrió preguntando al usuario si desde el inicio quiere añadir una nota, en caso de que no quiera añadir ninguna nota, obligatoriamente salta el mensaje de error hasta cumplir mínimo con el ingreso de tres notas.

```
lista = []
def main():
    respuesta = input("¿Desea agregar una nota? s/n: ")

    while respuesta == "s":
        nota = int(input('Ingrese la nota: '))
        lista.append(nota)
        respuesta = input("¿Desea agregar otra nota? s/n: ")

    while len(lista) < 3:

        print('Error, ingrese otra nota')
        agregar_nota = int(input('Ingrese la nota faltante: '))
        lista.append(agregar_nota)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
print(lista)
```

Edit:
Para calcular el promedio de una lista, debemos sumar la cantidad que dan eso números que se encuentren en ella.
Hay diferentes formas de hacerlo, pero estas son algunas de ellas:

Primera forma:

```
contador = 0 #Utilizamos un contador
elementos_lista = [1, 2, 3]
for promedio in elementos_lista:
    contador += promedio
print(contador)
```

Segunda forma:

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, elementos_lista))
```

Tercera forma:

```
print(sum(elementos_lista))
```

Una vez eliges la forma más conveniente la dividimos entre la cantidad de elementos que haya en la lista con el método `len` (éste método te permite contar la cantidad de elementos que hay en dicha lista).

```
contador = 0 #Utilizamos un contador
elementos_lista = [1, 2, 3]
for promedio in elementos_lista:
    contador += promedio
print(contador)
promedio_total = contador / len(elementos_lista)
print(promedio_total)
```

Modificado el código anterior, quedaría así:

```
lista = []
def main():
    respuesta = input("¿Desea agregar una nota? s/n: ")

    while respuesta == "s":
        nota = int(input('Ingrese la nota: '))
        lista.append(nota)
        respuesta = input("¿Desea agregar otra nota? s/n: ")

    while len(lista) < 3:

        print('Error, ingrese otra nota')
        agregar_nota = int(input('Ingrese la nota faltante: '))
        lista.append(agregar_nota)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
print(lista)

contador = 0 
for promedio in lista:
    contador += promedio
print(contador)
promedio_total = contador / len(lista)
print(f'El promedio es: {promedio_total}')
```

En caso de que ninguna te sirva, deberás modificar tu pregunta y añadir más información para poder ayudarte. Te recomiendo pasarte por el centro de ayuda para poder realizar una buena pregunta y obtengas una buena respuesta: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Si mira este ya me di a entender un poco mejor

Comment: Listo, checa de nuevo la respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: En caso de que no te convenza, te recomiendo mostrar tu código para poder orientarme y resolver tu inquietud con mayor exactitud.

Comment: Estoy revisando pero me sale error en la última línea

Comment: Qué te sale? Puedes mostrarme?

Comment: Ya lo vi era mio sin querer puse algo que no debía

Comment: Un detalle. Debes recordar en caso de que quieras poner valores decimales, debes modificar el tipo `int` a `float`, en la variable `nota`. Saludos!